# use Ubuntu at virtual box based on windows 7 cannot edit text

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-14.04, virtual-machine

I have a problem that 
1. my laptop is X86 win7 & install a virtual box.
2. Based on virtual box, I installed a Ubuntu.

Now I share a folder between win7 & Ubuntu.
And edit a bash file on windows by, ex UltraEdit.

After then, when I run the bash on Ubuntu.
It said:

***mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dvbpsi\r’: Protocol error
cp: cannot stat 'src/table/*.h': No such file or directory***

It seems that **\r** is wrong.

Instead, if I tried to store in virtual box, it shows the wrong msg below:
[image]

It seems that I CANNOT store anything from virtual OS to a shared folder.

Is there a smart way to resolve it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: At least some of your problems are because Windows uses different characters to represent the end of a line than Unix/Linux. Windows uses `\r\n` and Unix/Linux use just `\n`. If you want to edit files on Windows that will run on Linux, make sure you use an editor that can be configured to use the Linux end-of-line style of just `\n`. See for example http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/How_to_avoid_DOS_line_endings_in_Windows_tools

Answer (score 0):

UltraEdit can create, edit and save text files with **DOS** (\r\n) or **UNIX** (just \n) or **MAC** (just \r) line terminators.

The line terminator type is indicated for active file in status bar at bottom of UltraEdit main window.

The conversion between the various line terminator types can be done at any time in UltraEdit using for example the **DOS to UNIX** conversion command or on using *Line terminator* option in **Save As** dialog.

The default line ending type for new files can be also configured in configuration at
**Advanced - Settings/Configuration - File Handling - DOS/Unix/Mac Handling**.

I suggest following configuration settings for using UltraEdit mainly for editing Windows text files and only sometimes for Unix shell scripts:

- *Default file type for new files* ... DOS
- *Unix/Mac file detection/conversion* ... Automatically convert to DOS format
- *Only recognize DOS terminated lines (CR/LF) as new lines for editing* ... **not** *checked*
- *Save file as input format (Unix/Mac/DOS)* ... *checked*
- *Status bar shows original line terminator format (on disk)* ... *checked*

So creating/editing shell scripts on Windows with UNIX type of line termination is easy using UltraEdit on Windows being also available for Linux and Mac.